# Polkadot multisig - LiquidityRestrictions error to initiate a call from an account with < 20 DOT

Tags: polkadot, error, balances, multisig

The Polkadot account `1vSN9CPVLXJWsY3JbdRU9KjAFFAx88yvEVpU1ayjnhSephy` is a proxy, controlled by a multisig (`13oHAjv9gNbdVKFk6uosaiyRAm2ybC48VnJ47Ss8F8pY7NgR`).

All attempts to initiate an extrinsic with it (token transfer, bonding) end up in a failure with `LiquidityRestrictions` error.
example: https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/15084711-3
[image: extrinsic fail]

This account has 454.1998 DOT transferable, 20.2580 DOT reserved, nothing bonded nor locked. but even a 1 DOT transfer ends up in a failure.

[image: balance]

This account is also the root/toggler/nominator of the nomination pool #21.
https://polkadot.subscan.io/nomination_pool/21
But it has no tokens bonded to this pool.

Following the [referenda #111](https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/referendum/111) enacting the `nominationPools.minCreateBond` to 500 DOT, I suspect the runtime to check this amount on the pool's root, while storage doesn't consider it bonded.

Could anyone confirm this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is not in the Proxy account but in the available balance of the multisig initiator account, i.e. `12bLdVAgWiKHgFHtAaQstasMUWVq35oG9iwHCwsKoFFNoNrk`. As you can see in [this wiki page](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000181826-how-to-create-and-use-a-multisig-account) ("How to use a multisig account
" section), the account needs more than 20 DOTs available to initiate a multisig operation. The mentioned account only has 6.496 transferable DOTs at the moment. Can you please try to send more funds to this account and try again?

Comment: Thanks this is it!
Hope this post will help next ones who have to problem, I'll edit the title